# ls pipe to grep vs ls file glob

Tags: bash, grep, ls

when I use this to look to see if there is a particular file in a directory, `ls` piped to `grep` does not work

```
 casper@fooserver:/home/log$ ls -ltr | grep  *FOO-VOL2*
```

But when I use `ls` with the file globbing I get results:

```
casper@fooserver:/home/log$ ls -ltr  *FOO-VOL2*
-rw-rw-rw- 1 casper casper   11489 Sep 24 18:00 FOO-VOL2.20140924.log.gz
-rw-rw-rw- 1 casper casper   11885 Sep 25 18:00 FOO-VOL2.20140925.log.gz
-rw-rw-rw- 1 casper casper       0 Sep 26 08:00 FOO-VOL2.sessiondump.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 casper casper   60906 Sep 26 18:00 FOO-VOL2.20140926.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 casper casper   58503 Sep 29 09:00 FOO-VOL2.20140929.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 casper casper 8259128 Sep 29 09:00 FOO-VOL2.sys.log
```

What is the difference - the grep to pipe should work.

Comment: The are *very* different in the corner case where a filename matching `*FOO-VOL2*` contains a newline; the output of `ls` will span multiple lines, and `grep` (assuming a correct regex) will only show the line that contains `FOO-VOL2`.

Answer (score 5):

The shell expands the `*FOO-VOL2*` glob before executing anything, so the actual command you're running is this:

```
ls -ltr |
  grep FOO-VOL2.20140924.log.gz FOO-VOL2.20140925.log.gz FOO-VOL2.sessiondump.log \
       FOO-VOL2.20140926.log FOO-VOL2.20140929.log FOO-VOL2.sys.log
```

When run with those arguments, `grep` ignores the standard input coming to it from `ls` and searches inside the files `FOO-VOL2.20140925.log.gz`, `FOO-VOL2.sessiondump.log`, `FOO-VOL2.20140926.log`, 
`FOO-VOL2.20140929.log`, and `FOO-VOL2.sys.log` for the string "FOO-VOL2.20140924.log.gz".  And doesn't find it, which is probably not a surprise.

Also, `grep` regular expressions and shell glob patterns are different. The patterns you pass to `grep` are not anchored, so you don't need the equivalent of `*` on either side of the string you're looking for.  But if you did, `*` doesn't mean "any character" anyway; it means "0 or more of the previous character".  So as a `grep` expression, `*FOO-VOL2*` is not even valid. You want just `FOO-VOL2` or, as a literal translation from the glob even though it includes parts that aren't necessary here, `'.*FOO-VOL2.*'`.